# Check if row contains a nested item in DynamoDB?

Tags: sql, amazon-dynamodb, partiql

I am trying to use PartiQL with DynamoDB to perform SQL queries to check if a device is inactive and contains an error. Here's is the query I am using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "table" 
WHERE "device"."active" = 0 AND "device"."error" IS NOT NULL
```

However I've noticed that even if a device doesn't have the error item, the query still returns a row. How can I query a device that only contains the error item?

With error item

```
{
    "id": "value",
    "name": "value,
    "device": {
        "active": 0,
        "error": {
            "reason": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

Without error item

```
{
    "id": "value",
    "name": "value,
    "device": {
        "active": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `IS NOT MISSING` :) That's the partiql version of the filter expression operator function `attribute_exists`.

Given a table with a primary key PK, sort key SK, and the following data:

| PK | SK | myMap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 1 | {} |
| foo | 2 | {"test": {}} |

```
-- Returns both foo 1 and foo 2
SELECT * 
FROM "my-table"
WHERE "PK" = 'foo' AND "myMap"."test" IS NOT NULL
```

```
-- Returns just foo 2
SELECT * 
FROM "my-table"
WHERE "PK" = 'foo' AND "myMap"."test" IS NOT MISSING
```

Also make sure you specify the PK in the WHERE clause - otherwise, your query will be a full scan. Maybe that's what you want, though. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks! After searching for hours in all possible documentation, I finally a clear answer.